# Strange behavior using Python multiprocessing library

Tags: python, list, file-io, multiprocessing, pycharm

I am trying to read a file using python `multiprocessing` library but not getting the desired results. Here goes the code that I am using:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import itertools

partitioned = {}
partitioned['0-20'] = []
partitioned['20-40'] = []
partitioned['40-60'] = []
partitioned['60+'] = []
output = []

def map_func1(f):
    # for line in f:
    gen = f[14:15] #15 1=male 2=female
    age = f[17:19] #18-19
    htin = f[1947:1950] #1948-1950 tall in inches, self reported !888! !999!
    wtlbs = f[1950:1953] #1951-1953 wt in lbs, self reported !888! !999!
    ovwt = f[1963:1964] #1964 consider myself overweight 1,under 2,over 3, !8!, !9!
    chwt = f[1964:1965] #1965 change weight or stay same 1=more, 2=less, 3=same, !8!, !9!
    output.append([gen, age, htin, wtlbs, ovwt, chwt])
    return output

def partitioner(m):
    for element in m:
        if int(element[1]) < 20:
            output['0-20'].append(element)
        elif int(element[1]) < 40:
            output['20-40'].append(element)
        elif int(element[1]) < 60:
            output['40-60'].append(element)
        else:
            output['60+'].append(element)

    return partitioned

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=3)
    f = open('adult.dat')
    m = pool.map(map_func1, f)
    print len(output)
    print len(m)
    p = partitioner(m)
    print p
```

Here goes the output that I receive:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
0
20050
```

I have the following problems:

1. I don't understand why in the aforementioned code, the length of `output` is 0 and the length of the variable `m` is 20050. According to me, both, `output` and `m`, should be of length 20050.
2. Why the `TypeError()` in this case? Why can the argument not be a list in the `partitioner` function?
3. When I try to see the contents of the variable `m` in the debugging window, my system almost craps out. (I am using Ubuntu 13.10 and running Pycharm 3.1 on it!) I could understand this if the contents of the list I was trying to view were insanely huge, in this case they aren't. It is a list of 20050 lists, each having 6 elements.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was not returning the contents properly from the mapper function. Slight change in the code makes it work as required:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import itertools

partitioned = {}
partitioned['0-20'] = []
partitioned['20-40'] = []
partitioned['40-60'] = []
partitioned['60+'] = []

def map_func1(f):
    # for line in f:
    gen = f[14:15] #15 1=male 2=female
    age = f[17:19] #18-19
    htin = f[1947:1950] #1948-1950 tall in inches, self reported !888! !999!
    wtlbs = f[1950:1953] #1951-1953 wt in lbs, self reported !888! !999!
    ovwt = f[1963:1964] #1964 consider myself overweight 1,under 2,over 3, !8!, !9!
    chwt = f[1964:1965] #1965 change weight or stay same 1=more, 2=less, 3=same, !8!, !9!
    return [gen, age, htin, wtlbs, ovwt, chwt]

def partitioner(m):
    for element in m:
        if int(element[1]) < 20:
            partitioned['0-20'].append(element)
        elif int(element[1]) < 40:
            partitioned['20-40'].append(element)
        elif int(element[1]) < 60:
            partitioned['40-60'].append(element)
        else:
            partitioned['60+'].append(element)

    return partitioned

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=3)
    f = open('adult.dat')
    m = pool.map(map_func1, f)
    print m[0]
    p = partitioner(m)
    print len(p['60+'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to address your error, `partitioner` calls:

```
int(element[1])
```

But, per `map_func1`, `element1` is `age` which is defined:

```
age = f[17:19] #18-19
```

This is a two-item list slice, and is itself a list, so is not a valid argument to `int`.

For the others, I would suggest you output a sample to see what's in there, e.g.

```
print m[:5]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I figured out the issue. My map_func1 has to return "return [gen, age, htin, wtlbs, ovwt, chwt]"